Apache2 in Yocto build
I followed the instructions given in this post.
I can see that image is building fine. However httpd binary is not present on the target.
When I try to find any files related to httpd, they are not present.
I can see that in the download directory httpd-2.4.60.tar.bz2 was downloaded.
I am using following version of meta-openembedded:
commit 4ad41baed6236d499804cbfc4f174042d84fce97 (HEAD, repo/kirkstone-next, repo/kirkstone, m/kirkstone-6.x.y)
Author: Liyin Zhang <liyin.zhang.cn@windriver.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 11 16:55:32 2024 +0800

    sound-theme-freedesktop: Update SRC_URI
    
    Signed-off-by: Liyin Zhang <liyin.zhang.cn@windriver.com>
    Signed-off-by: Armin Kuster <akuster808@gmail.com>

Any suggestion on what I can do?

You are trying to build Kirstone release, but the post you mentioned is bit outdated and based on older BB language.
Try to do
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " apache2"

instead of:
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " apache2"

